# UITableView dosen't change the size of UIScrollView when adding Cells

Tags: ios, xcode, scrollview, tableview

The scrollView, which is there with UITableView dose not change it's size.
So I have a UITableView, where Cells are added by the User. Right after adding these cells, I'm calling

[self.tableView reloadData];

Now the tableView shows the new cells added by the User. fine. But, if the tableView get's larger, if it's too big to show everything in the view, it doesen't change the size of my scrollView. I have no scrollView in the view, aside from the "normal" scrollView, which comes with the UITableView. So I can't scroll to the last row, because the scrollView is "too small".
Is there anything I forgot? I'm thinking of something like

[self.tableView.scrollView reload];

I'm using the same concept in another class: The user is able to add cells and they're shown. But in the other class the scrollView "resizes" correctly.

Comment: what is your problem. you can't scroll the table view ??

Comment: Exactly, the tableView is larger Then the View, so I must scroll Down to See the last cell, but the scrollView is to small to let me see the Last cell

Comment: Why do you have a UITableview inside a UIScrollView? UITableView is a UIScrollView subclass and comes with scrolling and all the calculations for height built in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that you have table inside a scrollview. You need to change content size of scrollview after adding cells. Height of content size should change according to content in scrollview so that you can scroll through whole content.

**Updated answer:**

I think your tableview's frame is larger. It is crossing window's bounds. Try minimizing tableview's height.

Comment: No, I haven't, but maybe I can add a scrollView with a height of self.tableView.frame.size.height… i'll try that in a moment

Comment: I think your tableview's frame is larger. It is crossing window's bounds. Try minimizing tableview's height.

Comment: as @Rahul said, your tableview frame is most likely too large. See what the size is in the debugger or NSLog(@"%@", [NSValue valueWithCGRect:self.tableView.frame])

Comment: You guys were right, I don't know why, but I changed my tableView in Interface Builder to about 1/3 of the whole screen (looks strange in IB), but now it is working perfectly! Thank you!

Comment: I guess I know the reason, the problem was that I was testing with my iPhone 5, but the IB was set to 3.5 Inch, so my tableView was too small for iPhone 5!